# Does the Column build its children lazily in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Column can also have listview.builder, if the column builds all of its children at a time, does it build listview items at once too?

Comment: It builds a listview but not it's items - they are still build lazily by a listview - the easiest way to check it is to add some `print`s inside the builder

Comment: So column does not build items lazily, it builds all items at once, right?, in case of listview.builder, inside a column it builds listview but not its children, right?
@pskink

Comment: add a print inside the builder and you will see

Answer (score 1):

`Column` builds all of its children at once, but listview.builder builds lazily.

when you pass `childrens:` to `ListView`, it builds all at once. Only difference is `Column` shows all of its `childrens` in the screen while `ListView` has scroll functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` takes a specific space of screen with 2 constraints on that top space & bottom space.

```
============ (top constraint/pixel)
||||
||||
<This is the space of you ListView>
||||
||||
============ (bottom constraint/pixel)
```

If you scroll up, it will detect that items have been scrolled through pixel constraints and lazy load the next items. So if your parent widget is whatever `Container`, `Row`, `Column`, it will always be able to lazy loading. And that is the main difference between `Column` & `ListView.builder`, `Column` build everything in 1 time, and `ListView.builder` can use lazy loading.